# Incorrect rotation of a view controller in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, rotation

In my app I've been using the now deprecated shouldAutoRotateToFace method. Now when using the iOS 6 simulator, all of my subviews are rotated to portrait orientation while the device is in landscape. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I've already tried replacing should autorotate in my main view controller with the supportedOrientations method (or whatever it is that you're now supposed to use instead).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can log in to the Apple dev forums, [check out this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/727235).

Basically, this is the information that helped me:

---

**1.** I had to set `window.rootViewController = mainViewController` in

```objc
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

**2.** For view controllers where

```objc
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

**didn't** just return `YES`, I had to add

```objc
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

that returned the same value

**3.** Added

```objc
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |
            UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

to mainViewController.m

**4.** Added

```objc
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |
            UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

to appDelegate.m (I believe this is optional, for setting default values in case they're not specified in the app's Info.plist file, or in individual view controllers)

Since I want my code backwards compatible back to 3.0 I didn't use the *All* orientation masks, as I need to compile using XCode 4.3

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need - I tried all of these but separately, since I thought they were individual solutions.

Comment: "I had to set window.rootViewController = mainViewController" in the application's delegate is what did it for me.