# orientation methods on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios 6 orientation methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656070/ios-6-orientation-methods)

the orientation methods have changed in iOS 6. my whole app in portrait mode got to many view controllers (not tab bar view controllers) i just want to rotate one of my view controller to landscape mode (it actually displays a webView) when i rotate the device.the below method was working in xcode 4.4 but, it's not in Xcode.4.5

```
         - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
       (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
       interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
    interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );
```

the above method won't work in xcode 4.5 for this reason i have changed the below method       but even though its not working....plz any suggestions thanks.

```
    - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:                        UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    return self.modalViewController.shouldAutorotate;
     }  
     -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
       {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
          }
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650127/alternate-landscape-triggered-at-unwanted-view/14651219#14651219

Comment: See this for a [way to handle orientation in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12549513/119114), and please work on formatting the code you post.  This isn't very readable, as is.  Thanks.

Comment: **1.** you should define the supported orientations in the `Into.plist` file for your application. **2.** the `-shouldAutorotate` just contains `return YES;` or `return NO;` (no need to check the orientations again), and the supported orientations will be read from your `Info.plist` automatically by the iOS. (alternative solution: the supported orientations could be provided by the `-application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method as well.)

Comment: Hi Holex thanks for your answer. i defined the all orientations in the Into.Plist. but my application only supports Portrait.but i need to show only one ViewController in landscape mode and more over that ViewController displays a WebView.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you implementing supportedInterfaceOrientations as well ? you might want to.

Comment: thanks. for your reply is this the method u are asking about                                  -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
       {